# ASP.NET Namespace

Tags: asp.net, namespaces

What is the namespace the Default.aspx page resides in when I create an ASP.NET project?

And how to find the namespace of any other ASP.NET page in the project?

I am using VS2005. I first created a blank solution and then added a webSite to it.

When I click right-button and go to 'Add New Web Site' - menu I find the following template ASP.NEt WebSites(1st template), then I added this to my sln.

I am using C# and VS2005. This will not match VS2008 in this case.

Comment: This is dependant on the project type. Are you creating a new "Web Application" or creating a new "Web Site"?

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question very much, what type of web site did you add? There are two, web sites and web applications (I can't be more exact, I don't have 2005 on this machine)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Web Sites do not have/support namespace. Web Applications do.

To answer the question, since a new 'Web Site' is created, namespace doesn't come into play. As to how to access other WebForm page classes from a Webform page, I haven't figure a reason for that. And I do not think it is do-able (correct me if I'm wrong).

Anyway there are ways to get around. If you have some reuable business/UI/other logics used within a class of one the webforms, simply move those methods out to say XXX.cs file under App_Code. There is no need for namespace and you can use it within all the webform classes.

Comment: I need to inherit .aspx pages.

Comment: You mean u have a basepage.aspx with a codebind class "basepage". And you have a newpage.aspx which has a "newpage" class inherting "basepage"?If that is so, read this:
http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/3016.aspx under the section "What to watch out for". Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the code-behind (Default.aspx.cs in your case) of a page in question. There you will see your namespace. Aspx is an addition to the class in code-behind that is merged using the partial class declaration.

I just created a new web application project. This what the code-behind looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

So you see the "WebApplication1" namespace. You see it, right?

ADDED: So I created a web site project again to check that out. Okay, I confirm, I do not see any namespace declarations there. After googling a little bit I found this post:

[asp.net - Web Site vs. Web Application](http://reddnet.net/code/asp-net-web-site-vs-web-application/) (link fixed)

> The new compilation model threw out the visual studio project file itself, took asp.net back to the "compile-on-the-fly" concept, all but **eliminated the use of namespaces within a web site**, and radically altered the way UI template and the associated code-behind were arranged.

From the looks of it, it just throws all classes together, both page classes and your custom logic classes you usually put into `App_Code` folder. Class viewer also does not show page objects even if I wrap them in my custom namespaces, but it does so correctly along with the namespaces for declarations in the `App_Code` folder. I suppose the guys in VS team didn't mean you to care about namespaces for page classes.

Comment: Which planet do you live in? There are no namespace declarations in any asp.net code-behind file.

Comment: Are you kidding? Give me a minute, I'll get you an example.

Comment: I am using VS2005 and I never saw this happening in my Web projects.

Comment: I did this example in VS2008 Pro and I believe I saw more or less the same thing when I was using VS 2005. Maybe you were creating web site projects as opposed to web application projects? There the organization is somewhat different.

Answer (score 2):

Try defining an interface in the app code directory and have your code behind file implement the interface.