# Visual Studio 2010 sp1 The type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a weird issue with VS 2010 pro sp1, none of my custom classes (all in the same namespace) are coming up in intellisense.  I get the red swiggley lines under all my variable declarations and if I hover my mouse over them I get - The type or namespace name 'xxx' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

The strange part is that I have the correct using statement in place, everything is correct the project will even compile and run properly it's just annoying to not have intellisense with my custom classes while I'm developing these pages.  Something to note, it's a website project not a website application project.  I've reinstalled visual studio several times, I was able to fix the problem once before by recreating a new solution file but the issue showed up shortly after that again and I don't want to have to do that all the time.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Clean the solution, delete bin/obj folders, rebuild all.

Comment: Also, possible name conflict somewhere. For example, a class and enum with the same name, or property and method, and so on.

Comment: where exactly would I delete the bin/obj folders?  since this is a website project not a website application project the bin folder only contains dlls that are referenced in my website project.  Cleaning the solution doesn't seem to be an option for a website project either.

Comment: @AMissico if that were the case would the project still compile?  It does build successfully even though intellisense complains.  I can maybe try removing each class and adding them one by one to see if this is the case as well.  I'll report back when I do this.

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: BTW, there is no such concept as a "namespace" in a "Website" project.

Comment: Don't use web site "projects". They're strange creatures, different from all others.

Comment: @IrishChieftain can you elaborate more on what you mean by no such concept of a namespace in a website project?  All my custom classes were under a specific namespace I gave them, they resided in the app_code folder so I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that statement.

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251542/asp-net-namespace

Comment: @IrishChieftain interesting so giving my custom classes a namespace was pointless in my website project?  I realize that all my pages didn't have a namespace but I was able declare a namespace in the custom classes I created.  When I referenced one of those classes I could call it using namespace.classname

Comment: You could try removing them but I would still recommend sticking with the Web Application project to avoid snags in the future, esp. when using libraries :)

Comment: I did remove them one by one, it didn't help.

Comment: @pumm3l; Yes, it would compile because it is a namespace conflict. There is nothing wrong with the code, it is just IntelliSense "breaks" because it cannot handle the conflict. I suggest you clear out your 'VsWebCache' and other Visual Studio caches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch over to the Web Application project template. I've seen this happen time and time again with Website templates; they do not play nice with libraries especially if there are user controls involved. Do a search of Google or SO and you will find many similar questions on this topic.

Comment: I converted to a web application project template, everything is working fine again - thanks.  One of the things I liked about using the website project template was that I could change code behind without having to stop the project first if the project was running in visual studio.  I suppose I can deal with having to stop the project to modify page/custom classes to get intellisense to work.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for "barging in" on your post - perhaps the conversion to Web Application fixed your issue, but.....

**Clarification**:

> there is no such concept as a "namespace" in a "Website" project.

Unsure how the above started but its **inaccurate** - you can certainly have namespaces in an ASP.Net WebSite (and you **will** get Intellisense). This isn't about which paradigm is "better" - just hopefully clarified before this becomes *"accepted fact"*.

The `App_Code` folder is your friend (VS will ask you about it if you add a `Class` item:

[image: Web Site folder structure]

Namespaced.vb full source:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Namespace EdSFNS
    Public Class foo
        Public Property someInt As Integer
        Public Property someString As String
        Public Sub New()
        ...
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Yet another namespace (namespaced2.vb):

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Namespace StackOverFlowNS
    Public Class foo
        Public Property someInt As Integer
        Public Property someString As String
        Public Sub New()
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Intellisense in Razor page:

[image: Intellisense working 1] [image: Intellisense working 3]

[image: Intellisense working 2]

---

### Result:

[image: Namespaces in web sites work just fine]

---

HTH...

Comment: I thought so, I know you can define a namespace for a custom class....I've been working in this project as a website project for a while now and the issue that I'm encountering is pretty new.  I'm more curious as to the reason it's happening than fixing the problem which I already have.

Comment: @pumm3l I have experienced your issue - usually when there is a proxy class involved e.g. from a referenced web service. Updating/refreshing the (web service) reference fixes the annoyances (not errors, just as you have posted) for me.

Comment: People forget that the namespace is part of the data-type-name. There is no such data-type as `Object`. It is actually `System.Object`.