# ASP.NET, What namespace is used by default?

Tags: asp.net, namespaces

When I create a new Web Site, the Default.aspx has the @ Page directive automatically set to `Inherits="_Default"`. The codebehind file has `public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page` but no `namespace` is specified. Does this mean that a random namespace name is generated at compile time?

So, I would like to create a class to handle some database work, but not sure what namespace it would belong to. Do I explicitly create a namespace for this? I.e. if my class were in the `MyNamespace`, then the Default.aspx would have `Inherits="MyNamespace._Default"` and the codebehind would also be wrapped in `namespace MyNamespace{ ... }`? Your clarifications are appreciated.

Comment: basically, it just is not in a namespace ! As easy as that !

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251542/asp-net-namespace) question?

Comment: Yes, the answer is there. Thank you.

Comment: In summary, there are no namespaces in Web Sites. Your custom code goes to App_Code directory and the classes are then referenced automatically in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any namespaces in web sites - when your site is compiled, the DLL's go to the App_Code directory and the classes are then referenced automatically in your project.