# How do I put the namespace in a C#.aspx page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm looking specifically for `DateTime` as well as other essential namespaces.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question makes sense, I'll leave it for people familiar with the technology. I read this though ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251542/asp-net-namespace

Comment: <%@ Import namespace="value" %>

Comment: What view engine are you using?  WebForms? Razor? other?

Answer (score 0):

As stated at [@Import](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation page, the directive is `<%@ Import namespace="value" %>`. However, ASP.NET will automatically import many of important namespaces, including `System` (full list of namespaces is documentation page). [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) type is defined in `System`, so you don't need import it explicitly.